# Android Room error: TypeConverter not recognised for List of Enums

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

The Room library is not recognizing a `TypeConverter` I created for a `List` of enums. However, when I change this to an `ArrayList` of enums it works fine. Anyone has any idea why and what can I do to make this work with `List`? (Using List in Kotlin is easier and I really don't wanna be converting back and forwards to `ArrayList` just because of this).

Here is my code:

My model:

```
@Entity
data class Example(@PrimaryKey val id: String?,
                   val name: String,
                   var days: List<DayOfWeek>?)
```

`DayOfWeek` is an enum:

```
enum class DayOfWeek {

    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY,
    SUNDAY;

    val value: Int
        get() = ordinal + 1


    companion object {

        private val ENUMS = DayOfWeek.values()

        fun of(dayOfWeek: Int): DayOfWeek {
            if (dayOfWeek < 1 || dayOfWeek > 7) {
                throw RuntimeException("Invalid value for DayOfWeek: " + dayOfWeek)
            }

            return ENUMS[dayOfWeek - 1]
        }

    }

}
```

My `TypeConverter`:

```
private const val SEPARATOR = ","

class DayOfWeekConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun daysOfWeekToString(daysOfWeek: List<DayOfWeek>?): String? {
        return daysOfWeek?.map { it.value }?.joinToString(separator = SEPARATOR)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToDaysOfWeek(daysOfWeek: String?): List<DayOfWeek>? {
        return daysOfWeek?.split(SEPARATOR)?.map { DayOfWeek.of(it.toInt()) }
    }

}
```

And I set it in my DB class like this:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Example::class), version = 1)
@TypeConverters(DayOfWeekConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun exampleDao(): ExampleDao

}
```

My DAO looks like this:

```
@Dao
interface ExampleDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM example")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Example>>

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun save(examples: List<Example>)

}
```

The error I get with this code is:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
e: 

e:     private java.util.List<? extends com.example.DayOfWeek> days;
```

Like I said above, if I change the `days` property to `ArrayList<DayOfWeek>` (and make the changes to `ArrayList` in `DayOfWeekConverter`) then everything works fine. If anyone can help me figure this out and tell me how I can use `List` here it'd be of great help, it is driving me crazy :/.

Comment: Please post your 'ExampleDao' class.

Comment: The DAO seems irrelevant for the issue I'm having @PravinDivraniya, but I have added it now anyway in case it helps you figure out the problem. Cheers.

Comment: I came across the same problem. Given that apparently, this is not possible, I created a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69164099

Comment: @Franco, I've updated my solution to compile with Room

Comment: Thanks @TomekPolański, I will try to test it when I have time and I'll accept your answer if I can verify that it works as expected.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For some reason, Room does not like Kotlin `List`, but when I've replaced `List` with `MutableList` it started to work:

```
@Entity
data class Example(@PrimaryKey val id: String,
                   val name: String,
                   var days: MutableList<DayOfWeek>?)

class DayOfWeekConverter {
    companion object {

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun daysOfWeekToString(daysOfWeek: MutableList<DayOfWeek>?): String? =
                daysOfWeek?.map { it.value }?.joinToString(separator = SEPARATOR)

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun stringToDaysOfWeek(daysOfWeek: String?): MutableList<DayOfWeek>? =
                daysOfWeek?.split(SEPARATOR)?.map { DayOfWeek.of(it.toInt()) }?.toMutableList()
    }
}
```

This is not perfect solution, but hope you can investigate more with that.

Also you need to change `@PrimaryKey` to be not nullable

Comment: I seem to remember that I tried it and it didn't work, but I'm not sure as it was months ago. If I have time I might try it but I'm quite busy atm so I won't be able to do it for a while. Did you try this yourself?

Comment: I finally got some time to try this and indeed it worked with `MutableList` :), thanks @ TomekPolański! 

Thinking about it I guess it makes sense, as `List`s in Kotlin are immutable and hence you cannot add values to them, which is maybe what Room is trying to do in the background.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you have to add the @Converters annotation to the ROOM DATABASE as well. I didn't, and it kept on giving me errors. See also https://adrianhall.github.io/android/2018/08/08/converting-types-with-room-and-kotlin/.

Answer (score 4):

The full signature of `List` in Kotlin is `List<out E>`(`List<? extend E>` in Java), it doesn't make any sense to convert such generic type. In other words, Room doesn't know if the input is a `DayOfWeek` or its subclass.

As for `ArrayList` and `MutableList`, their full signature is `ArrayList<E>` and `MutableList<E>` correspondingly, the input type is fixed and hence Room knows how to convert it.

Answer (score -1):

We have no way to store and get a List enum without array list. Room does not support it. But if you want to avoid using array list, you can create an object ListDayOfWeek with List is an attribute. I tried it and it's ok. If you need code, please reply here. I will post it.

Comment: I was already aware of this workaround, but I don't find it acceptable as it's not scalable. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You should not store it like that into your database. Better build something like that and store it as int:

```
enum class DaysOfWeek(var bitValue: Int) {
    Monday(64),
    Tuesday(32),
    Wednesday(16),
    Thursday(8),
    Friday(4),
    Saturday(2),
    Sunday(1);
}
```

Finally your utility functions to convert from/to enum.

```
fun daysToBitValue(days: EnumSet<DaysOfWeek>): Int {
        var daysBitValue = 0
        for (`val` in days) daysBitValue += `val`.bitValue
        return daysBitValue
}


private fun fromBitValues(origBitMask: Int): EnumSet<DaysOfWeek> {

        val ret_val = EnumSet.noneOf(DaysOfWeek::class.java)

        var bitMask = origBitMask

        for (`val` in DaysOfWeek.values()) {
            if (`val`.bitValue and bitMask == `val`.bitValue) {
                bitMask = bitMask and `val`.bitValue.inv()
                ret_val.add(`val`)
            }
        }

        if (bitMask != 0) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Bit mask value 0x%X(%d) has unsupported bits 0x%X.  Extracted values: %s", origBitMask, origBitMask, bitMask, ret_val))
        }

        return ret_val
  }
```

Now you can either store an int and get the weekdays later:

```
@Entity
data class Example(@PrimaryKey val id: String?,
                   val name: String,
                   var days: Int = 0)
```

or you use the enum and write a proper typeconverter for that.

```
@Entity
data class Example(@PrimaryKey val id: String?,
                   val name: String,
                   var days: EnumSet<DaysOfWeek>?) 


class DayOfWeekConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun daysOfWeekToString(daysOfWeek: EnumSet<DayOfWeek>?) =
        daysOfWeek?.let{ YourUtilities.daysToBitValue(it) }

    @TypeConverter
    fun intToDaysOfWeek(daysOfWeek: Int?) = 
        daysOfWeek?.let {  YourUtilities.fromBitValues(it) } 
}
```

You can loop through the enum and get all days by using

```
for (aDaysOfWeekEnumSet in daysOfWeekEnumSet) 
             info{ "day = ${aDaysOfWeekEnumSet.name"}
```

Code is untested because im not on my Computer, but this should show the concept which works better then storing an enum (which is just an alias to a predefined value!)

Comment: I think you didn't read my code above, I'm already trying to save it as a list of ints, not enums, so your answer doesn't address my issue.

Comment: Thats Why i wrote a Working example. You  dont  Need a list if  you solve  it bitwise. Try  to   understand my Code. Thats the  Proper Way  storing week days.

Comment: I think I was not clear in my previous comment, I'm already saving this as a String, which is composed of the list of ints concatenated, not trying to save the list itself as you seem to think, it's all in my code above. 

I read your code but I'm not sure why solving it bitwise "is the proper way of storing weekdays", I don't think it's "the proper" way, it is just another workaround different to the one I already used. In the end, what I want is not another workaround, but to understand why this doesn't work with `List` and if there is a way to use it without having to add extra code.